# Django ORM Cross Product

Tags: sql, django, orm, outer-join

I  have three models:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    pass

class IssueType(models.Model):
    pass

class IssueTypeConfigPerCustomer(models.Model):
    customer=models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    issue_type=models.ForeignKey(IssueType)
    class Meta:
        unique_together=[('customer', 'issue_type')]
```

How can I find all tuples of (custmer, issue_type) where there is no IssueTypeConfigPerCustomer object?

I want to avoid a loop in Python. A solution which solves this in the DB would be preferred.

Background: for every customer and for every issue-type, there should be a config in the DB.

Comment: Where does config come in?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I updated the question. I hope it is more clear now:  for every customer and for every issue-type, there should be a config in the DB (cross product).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can afford to make one database trip for each issue type, try something like this untested snippet:

```python
def lacking_configs():
    for issue_type in IssueType.objects.all():
        for customer in Customer.objects.filter(
                issuetypeconfigpercustomer__issue_type=None
            ):
            yield customer, issue_type

missing = list(lacking_configs())
```

This is probably OK unless you have a lot of issue types or if you are doing this several times per second, but you may also consider having a sensible default instead of making a config object mandatory for each combination of issue type and customer (IMHO it is a bit of a design-smell).

[update]

> I updated the question: I want to avoid a loop in Python. A solution which solves this in the DB would be preferred.

In Django, every `Queryset` is either a list of Model instances or a `dict` (`values` querysets), so it is impossible to return the format you want (a list of `tuples` of Model) without some Python (and possibly multiple trips to the database).

The closest thing to a cross product would be using the "extra" method without a `where` parameter, but it involves raw SQL and knowing the underlying table name for the other model:

```python
missing = Customer.objects.extra(
    select={"issue_type_id": 'appname_issuetype.id'},
    tables=['appname_issuetype']
)
```

As a result, each Customer object will have an extra attribute, "issue_type_id", containing the id of one IssueType. You can use the `where` parameter to filter based on `NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM appname_issuetypeconfigpercustomer WHERE issuetype_id=appname_issuetype.id AND customer_id=appname_customer.id)`. Using the `values` method you can have something close to what you want - this is probably enough information to verify the rule and create the missing records. If you need other fields from IssueType just include them in the `select` argument.

In order to assemble a list of `(Customer, IssueType)` you need something like:

```python
cross_product = [
    (customer, IssueType.objects.get(pk=customer.issue_type_id))
    for customer in 
    Customer.objects.extra(
        select={"issue_type_id": 'appname_issuetype.id'},
        tables=['appname_issuetype'],
        where=["""
           NOT EXISTS (
               SELECT 1 
               FROM appname_issuetypeconfigpercustomer 
               WHERE issuetype_id=appname_issuetype.id 
                AND customer_id=appname_customer.id
           )
        """]
    )
]
```

Not only this requires the same number of trips to the database as the "generator" based version but IMHO it is also less portable, less readable and violates DRY. I guess you can lower the number of database queries to a couple using something like this:

```python
missing = Customer.objects.extra(
    select={"issue_type_id": 'appname_issuetype.id'},
    tables=['appname_issuetype'],
    where=["""
       NOT EXISTS (
           SELECT 1 
           FROM appname_issuetypeconfigpercustomer 
           WHERE issuetype_id=appname_issuetype.id 
             AND customer_id=appname_customer.id
       )
    """]
)
issue_list = dict(
    (issue.id, issue)
    for issue in 
    IssueType.objects.filter(
        pk__in=set(m.issue_type_id for m in missing)
    )
)
cross_product = [(c, issue_list[c.issue_type_id]) for c in missing]
```

Bottom line: in the best case you make two queries at the cost of legibility and portability. Having sensible defaults is probably a better design compared to mandatory config for each combination of Customer and IssueType.

This is all untested, sorry if some homework was left for you.

Comment: I updated the question: I want to avoid a loop in Python. A solution which solves this in the DB would be preferred.

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to resort to raw SQL then, this is beyond what you can do in one pass using more convenient ORM methods.